# 2 seperate Magento installs sometimes using each others cache - possible Memcached issue

Tags: magento, memcached

I have several Magento sites running on my dedicated server. 2 of which are configured to use memcached like so:

```
<cache>
    <prefix>alphanumeric</prefix>
    <backend>memcached</backend>
    <memcached>
        <servers>
            <server>
                <host><![CDATA[127.0.0.1]]></host>
                <port><![CDATA[11211]]></port>
                <persistent><![CDATA[1]]></persistent>
            </server>
        </servers>
    <compression><![CDATA[0]]></compression>
    <cache_dir><![CDATA[]]></cache_dir>
    <hashed_directory_level><![CDATA[]]></hashed_directory_level>
    <hashed_directory_umask><![CDATA[]]></hashed_directory_umask>
    <file_name_prefix><![CDATA[]]></file_name_prefix>
  </memcached>
</cache>
```

(both use this excact code in etc/local.xml)

Sometimes one of the sites starts to use/see the others cache. Flushing the cache within Magento sorts everything out again for a week or two.

anyone know what might be causing this? I'm wondering whether I need to set the prefix differently for each Magento site perhaps?

Thanks

Comment: This is what happens when you get stuck on "cargo cult" cut'n paste programming tactics. <prefix>alphanumeric</prefix> when you read further means replace alphanumeric with something like mage1 and mage2 so each instance has a prefix identifier to separate the cachey goodness.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, exactly. You need to set a different  for each instance.
I usually use the DB name, that way it's guaranteed to be shared by cluster instances that also share a database. Separate instances with a different database will also have their own cache pool.

But of course any unique prefix per instance will work.

Comment: Thanks Vinai. So I just need to change <prefix>alphanumeric</prefix> to <prefix>mysite1</prefix> (& <prefix>mysite2</prefix>)?

Answer (score 1):

I have **never** seen Magento able to use the prefix correctly.

Especially in the situation you have given, you should just be running two instances of Memcache.

1. If you want to flush the entire cache, without obliterating the cache for both stores
2. If you have a far more active store than another, the cache contents will be continually pushed out of the cache (due to Memcache being cyclic), making it redundant for one of your sites.

I would also strongly suggest reading this http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/what-is-memcache-actually-caching-in-magento/